# Multiple Tables of same Database on the same site

Tags: php, sql

I want to display 9 different tables from my sql database in 9 different html created tables on the website.

In detail: I have 9 tables ("dt_bookmarks_01", "dt_bookmarks_02" etc.) with 4 columns "id" (which is primary and auto increment), icon (for favicon), link (url) and text (for the display text).

I've created 9 different html tables with bootstrap and want to output the content of each table in a different bootstrap table of my site.

My problem is that i have no idea how to get different "foreaches" or counter for each different table.

To automaticaly add new rows to the bootstrap table I use the count and foreach function. problem here is: I dont know how to seperate them from each other. If i have 4 entries in sql table 1 it multiplies the one and only entrie of sql table 2 to match the current count of 4.

I am very new to sql and php so I guess I just miss some fundamental functions or something.

document header:

php
    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM dt_bookmarks_01, dt_bookmarks_02";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

```
while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$conn->close();
```

and for the html table I use:

php

```
<tbody>

    <!--begin: SQL Selection -->
    <?PHP 
    $count = 0;
        foreach($rows as $item){

            if (!empty($item['icon'])) {
                $icon = '<img src="assets/media/bm-icons/'. $item['icon'] . '">';
            }else{
                $icon = '<img src="assets/media/bm-icons/default.png">';
            }

            $count++;
            echo "<tr>";
            /*echo "<td>" . $count . "</td>";*/
            echo "<td>&ensp;" . $icon . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href=\"" . $item['link'] . "\"'>" . $item['text'] . "</a> </td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=" . $item['id'] . "\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md\"'><i class=\"la la-edit\" title=\"Edit\"></i></a> &nbsp; ";
            echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $item['id'] . "\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md\"'><i class=\"la la-trash\" title=\"Delete\"></i></a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
    ?>

    <!--end: SQL Selection -->
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why do you have 9 bookmarks table? If they all contain bookmarks merge them into a single table.

Comment: Because i'am very new to sql and php. Im glad i got this working for a single table and i have no idea how to adress specific links from the bookmark-table to display in a different bootstrap table. I have 9 categories like cmmunities, ressources etc. and i want to add, edit and delete them seperatly later.

Comment: You need another table which will hold your categories and then link it to your bookmarks table, singular.

Comment: I'm not sure but can i add it like this in the foreach function if i add a column called category? `foreach($rows as $item where category = categoryname)`

Comment: okay.. my "idea" isn't working so i guess this was a stupid question, sorry. Any tips what Ii should read/learn to get this working what i want? This would be helpfully enough. No need to just write me the code, i am willing to learn.

Comment: The problem is that your question does not seem to be clear enough. Could you put it in simpler words?

Comment: Of course, i will try my best, thank you :)
I dont understand what you mean by "link it to your bookmarks table, singular" so i've tried to filter it there by adding `WHERE` but this doesnt worked.
So i've tried to use seperate `$sql = "SELECT` request to filter it there and output different foreach (i dont even know if i can output multiple foreach..).
So overall i would say i know nothing to do. I just sitting here the whole day and just try different things in trial and error and nothing worked so i guess i just dont know something fundamentaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a database on hand to give you an answer with complete code, but here is the idea:

```
<?php

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++)
    {
        $query = "SELECT index1,index2 FROM dt_bookmarks_0$i";

        echo "<h1>This is the content of table $i</h1>";

        # RUN THE QUERY HERE !!!

        echo "<table>";

            # EXTRACT THE RESULTS
            foreach $rows as $item
            {
                echo "<tr><td>$item[index1]</td><td>$item[index2]</td></tr>"
            }

        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br><br>";
    }

?>
```

- Loop on your tables.
- In each table loop, you output the HTML code to display it's content.
- Avoid `SELECT *`, specify your indexes (research "sql why avoid SELECT *")
- So you loop twice.  One time to go through the tables, the other to loop on the results.

Comment: First of all thank you for this awesome example. Meanwhile.. after a long night I've got it working by using php if, elseif, else commands. But i will also try what you have posted.

so thank you both for your great tips and advices. =)

ps: i will follow your advice of removing the `SELECT *` thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

so here is the new working code.
header:

```php
<?PHP 
    require_once('/htdocs/_nt/mysql/data.php');

    $sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM dt_bookmarks";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $conn->close();                                                     
?>
```

and for the table output:

```php
<?PHP 
$count = 0;
    foreach($rows as $item){

        if ($item['category'] == talk) {
            $count++;
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>&ensp;" . $icontalk . "</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href=\"" . $item['url'] . "\"'>" . $item['text'] . "</a> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }else{
                echo "";
                }
    }   
?>
```